Struct with fields of List type, but set to null: Heap allocation?
Consider a struct like this:
struct ExampleStruct
{
    public int ID;
    public List<ExampleStruct> children;
}

Would the following line of code create an object on the heap?
ExampleStruct exStrct = new Examplestruct() {ID = 5, children = null};


No it won't. You can check the memory graph in SharpLab.

One unrelated gotcha that you might not be aware of: in the above SharpLab example, the value v1 has no relation to v2.children[0], because v1 has been copied when it was inserted into v2.children.

@GoodNightNerdPride Thanks for the memory graph, that is a great feature. If you make your comment an answer, I'll accept it.

Of course, if exStrct can have it's lifetime extended (by being captured by a lambda, being in an async or iterator generated method, etc) then it will itself be placed in a heap object. Don't try to learn a billion separate rules for when/where memory allocations occur; if it's actually important for your specific situation, profile.


Would the following line of code create an object on the heap?

No. Since Examplestruct is a value type memory for it will be allocated on stack. Since you are not creating an instance of List<ExampleStruct> (which is a reference type) there is no need to allocate memory on the heap.
null denotes:

a literal that represents a null reference, one that does not refer to any object. null is the default value of reference-type variables

So there is nothing on the heap to point to, so no need to allocate anything there.
There are multiple ways to check this. For example by using GC.GetTotalAllocatedBytes(Boolean):
// "warm up"
Measure(() => new ExampleStruct() {ID = 5, children = null}, 10); 

Measure(() => new ExampleStruct() {ID = 5, children = null}, 10000);
Measure(() => new ExampleStruct() {ID = 5, children = new List<ExampleStruct>()}, 10000);

static void Measure(Action action, int iterations)
{
    var cur = GC.GetTotalAllocatedBytes(true);
    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
    {
        action();
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"Total Allocated Bytes: {GC.GetTotalAllocatedBytes(true) - cur:N0}");
}

Which prints "on my machine":
Total Allocated Bytes: 2,008
Total Allocated Bytes: 0
Total Allocated Bytes: 320,288


If you put this code inside a test class... and set two breakpoints at the arrange and assert calls, you will be able to use the diagnotics window in VS2022 to inspect the details
Microsoft documentation for VS2022
struct ExampleStruct
{
    public int ID;
    public List<ExampleStruct> children;
}

public class StackOverflowStructQ
{
    [Fact]
    public void Method_Condition_Expectation()
    {
        // Arrange
        ExampleStruct es = new() { ID = 1, children = [] };

        // Act

        // Assert
        Assert.NotNull(es.children);
    }
}

The when the first breakpoint is hit - "take a snapshot" from the Diagnostics window.
You should be able to drill down and see "Referenced Objects".  This means the reference is stored in the struct, but the object it references is stored on the heap.
So try and keep your structs lightweight.  If you need to reference objects which will ultimately reside on the heap, probably best to use a class?

The question was about children = null not about children = []

Surely the question "eludes" to where that object will eventually reside?  Leaving it null for the lifetime or scope is meaningless?

@PureAlpha With the question I refer to the case that children is permanently set to null. It is clear to me that a heap allocation takes place as soon as a non-null list is assigned. But I was not sure about the null case.

But thanks for the hint how to measure the references with visual studio, that is quite useful!

You're very welcome! Pleased I could offer up something good :)
